# Help identifying a component on an old computer PCB

Tags: identification

I was hoping someone may be able to identify this component in an old (80-90s) computer.  I have both the schematic symbol and a photo of the actual component.

Further to that, how would I identify any associated value since it has nothing printed on it except a yellow band (does that convey much information?)

[image: Component]

In context:

[image: Mouse Socket]

Comment: I don't recognise the schematic symbol but the photo appears to be that of a zero-ohm resistor (wire jumper).  These wire jumpers are put in packages similar to resistors so that can be used in the automatic component-insertion machine.

Comment: I see.  So "L" might stand for "Link"?

Comment: Or Lousy inductor (lol)

Comment: well, as Sunnyskyguy says, L is usually an inductor. I think the only way forward here would be to put things in a larger context – what circuit is this used in?

Comment: Thanks All for your help so far.  I have added the section of the schematic where that component is from as further context.  This is the socket where you plug in the mouse.  That component appears to be used on every pin of the connector.  If you would like to see an even broader context (ie: the full computer schematic) let me know.

Comment: A Ferrite Bead maybe?

Comment: Hmm. It does look a lot like the IEEE 315 schematic symbol for a ferrite bead

Comment: Context helps.  I think that WesleyLee nailed it - appears to be a ferrite bead used for EMI suppression.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ferrite bead for suppressing electromagnetic interference. Component value can't be determined from the yellow band alone and measurements without specialized equipment is difficult.